# Does SonarQube count comment blocks in duplicated code?

Tags: sonarqube

Simple question.  SonarQube has a duplicate code scanner.  Does it examine comment blocks in this algorithm?  If I have 1000 source files with the same copyright header, will it detect these as duplicated code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [SonarQube documentation on duplications](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Duplications):

> SonarQube allows to detect "Type 2" duplications which means :  structurally/syntactically identical fragments except for variations in literals and comments.

So your copyright header will not be counted as duplication.